# The images do not align more in wordpress after adding icon to zoom

Tags: wordpress, css-float

I put a magnifying glass icon in my images with a code that I found here on this site. The code works perfect, the problem is that now I can no longer align the images to the center and right side because the parent element needs to float: left, how can I solve this?

```
    <a href="#" class="gallerypic">
      <img src="[url]" width="32" height="32" class="ALIGNRIGHT/ALIGNCENTER">
      <span class="zoom-icon"></span>
    </a>

a.gallerypic{
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #666;
  float:left;
}

a.gallerypic span.zoom-icon{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  left:40%;
  top:35%;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity:0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

a.gallerypic:hover span.zoom-icon{
  visibility:visible;
}
```